# Long phrase translation: あの子とも違う秘密を持ったみたいで後ろめたい気分だ

Tags: translation, parsing

> **Context**: 15-year boy speaking to himself
>   あの子とも 違う秘密を持ったみたいで後ろめたい気分だ

I brought this long phrase here because I have several points of doubt in it.

**First**: あの子とも doesn't seem to be the same as [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1561/what-are-the-meanings-of-%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82-tomo-and-%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%82%89-kashira) or [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3229/what-is-the-%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82-in-this-sentence-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AF%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%92%E5%AD%A6%E3%81%B0%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E6%9A%AE%E3%82%89%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%81%AB%E5%B1%85%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82). I suspect it is just an emphasis (like: "That kid!!"), but I would like someones confirmation, just to be sure.

**Second**: 違う秘密 Another secret, right?

**Third**: 持ったみたい Now, this one I really have no idea :) Is it even parsed like that? Like "Motta Mitai" being something on its own...

**Last**: 後ろめたい気分だ Ok, he's feeling guilty.

So, can someone provide explanation for these parts (specially the first and third)? A full translation would also be desirable, to see how these things connect.

Comment: Ideally you would break this question up into several more generalized separate questions instead of asking 4 in 1.

Comment: @ssb, thinking about ideally, I agree with you. The problem is that I don't know if I'm even parsing the questions correctly, so I wouldn't be sure where to break...

Comment: Interpretation of this 「とも」 is rather difficult without the context. Who does this "あの子" refer to, maybe a girl? And does this boy know something related to あの子's secret, before this sentence was spoken?

Comment: @naruto あの子 is in fact a girl. Basically, this girl talks and hugs the speaker (against his will) prior to that. 
Right after this, the girl he likes finds them just talking, and asks what they were doing. The speaker "lies", saying that nothing really happened 「特に何をしてたってわけじゃっ」, and then thinks to himself:  「ごめんやっぱちょっとだけしてたかも。。。」
My question is about what comes right after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know what "後ろめたい" is, so let's concentrate on the first half.

「～みたいだ」 is "It seems ～" or "Looks like ～". 「持ったみたいだ」 can be translated as "It seems that I had ～".

> 彼女とも違う秘密を持ったみたいだ。

This sentence is ambiguous by itself. Without any context given, I thought of two possible interpretations:

> 彼女と`の間に`も違う秘密を持ったみたいだ。
>   It seems that I made a different secret *also with her*.

The boy shared a secret with someone else before this. Now he (unintentionally) created another secret with this girl, too. (Yes it's something about triangle relationship.)

- あの子と = with that person (girl)
- も = also

> 彼女`の`とも違う秘密を持ったみたいだ。
>   彼女`の秘密`とも違う秘密を持ったみたいだ。
>   It seems that I made a secret that is *even different from her secret*.

- Aと違うB = B which is different from A
- も = also, even

The boy knew something about the girl's secret, and was worrying about that. But now he feels sorry because he has another secret of his own.

---

And now that we have adequate amount of context given, I think the first interpretation is more likely here, although I don't know what "the first secret with someone else" actually is.

Comment: @Choko けさなくても……

Comment: Yes, the first interpretation makes total sense, it just happens that the speaker and the girl who asks already share a secret.
Now, when you say: 「(終止形 of verb) ＋ みたいだ」, what is the verb in question? looking [here](http://www.jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A3&eng=&dict=edict) there are lots of verbs starting with 持っ...

Comment: Ah, sorry, actually I'm not good at explaining with grammars, and maybe I'm wrong there...

Comment: Do you know what "持った" mean, anyway? If not, its related to 促音便 but I don't think I can explain this well...

Comment: I don't. But I think this question is already over with... For curiosity sake I will open a new question specifically about it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: 自己レス。2通りの解釈がありえることを疑う人がいるかもしれないのですが、何の文脈もなしに「私には彼とも違う夢があります」と言われたら、やっぱり「彼の夢とは異なる、私自身の夢」とも「彼との間にも、もう1つの夢」とも解釈できる気がします。うーん微妙。