# What does 持った mean?

Tags: words, etymology

If context is needed, please consult [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17487/long-phrase-translation-%E3%81%82%E3%81%AE%E5%AD%90%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E9%81%95%E3%81%86%E7%A7%98%E5%AF%86%E3%82%92%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E5%BE%8C%E3%82%8D%E3%82%81%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E6%B0%97%E5%88%86%E3%81%A0) previous question.

So, there's [a bunch](http://www.jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A3&eng=&dict=edict) of verbs related to "持っ" but how can any of them evolve to 持った?

Comment: It's the past tense form of 持つ. 持った = "owned; used to own". I think you should probably go through a lesson of how Japanese verb conjugation works in general. Here's a really good one: http://japanese.about.com/od/grammarlessons/a/031101a.htm

Comment: @Ataraxia This was officially the most ridiculous question I could make! Thanks for pointing out 持つ

Comment: Haha no problem! Are you teaching yourself Japanese? If so it's an understandable mistake. Japanese verb forms are really confusing if you don't have formal instruction on them.

Comment: "owned; used to own" is 持っていた, not 持った.

Comment: @Ataraxia, yes, self-learner. But for time enough for not making such a blunder :) This was actually part of a previous question, I think the general context off that confused me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The past tense ～た attaches to the 連用形 "continuative form" of verbs, which for consonant stem verbs is formed by adding `-i-` to the stem, and for vowel stem verbs is formed by adding nothing.

For vowel stem verbs, this is fairly simple:

```
    寝る       ne-ru   →    　寝た    ne-ta
    見る       mi-ru   →    　見た    mi-ta
```

For consonant stem verbs, it's more complicated.  Depending on which consonant the stem ends with, we find an additional set of sound changes:

```
    書く      kak-u    →   *書きた   kak-i-ta    →    書いた  ka-i-ta　
    脱ぐ      nug-u    →   *脱ぎた   nug-i-ta    →    脱いだ  nu-i-da　
    話す    hanas-u    →    話した hanas-i-ta
    持つ      mot-u    →   *持ちた   mot-i-ta    →    持った   mot-ta　
    死ぬ      sin-u    →   *死にた   sin-i-ta    →    死んだ   sin-da　
    運ぶ    hakob-u    →   *運びた hakob-i-ta    →    運んだ hakon-da　
    噛む      kam-u    →   *噛みた   kam-i-ta    →    噛んだ   kan-da　
    やる      yar-u    →   *やりた   yar-i-ta    →    やった   yat-ta　
    言う       iw-u    →   *言いた    iw-i-ta    →    言った    it-ta
```

Note that /w/ disappears before all vowels except /a/, so `iw-u` is 言う, `iw-anai` is 言わない, etc.

Three otherwise regular consonant stem verbs are irregular here:

```
    行く       ik-u    →   *行きた    ik-i-ta    →    行った    it-ta　
    問う      tow-u    →   *問いた   tow-i-ta    →    問うた   too-ta　
    請う      kow-u    →   *請いた   kow-i-ta    →    請うた   koo-ta
```

These last two reflect western sound changes, while the regular verbs reflect eastern sound changes.

And our irregular verbs are irregular as usual:

```
    する       suru    →    　した      si-ta
    来る       kuru    →    　来た      ki-ta
```

The same changes apply when adding て, たり, たら, or たって rather than た.

---

In this answer, the `*` symbol indicates that a form is considered incorrect in Modern Japanese, and is included only to show you how the forms "evolved" (as you asked).

Comment: The vowel/consonant stem dichotomy is at first glance a useful one here, but looking at やる being posited as an example of a consonant-stem verb I get the feeling that やる can only be identified as such by working backwards from the past form; otherwise what would distinguish it from 寝る and 見る?

Comment: @chigusa Vowel stem verbs always have `i` or `e` as their final vowels, never `a`.