# Attack on Titan episode 2 - What does preacher say?

Tags: translation, anime, religion

I am translating 進撃の巨人. Below is a sentence from the transcript of the second episode.

Here the link for reference: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XT7gHjFO8jft8DAQCVpPfmU3DreCsraJVYC-NPtmv5g/edit

Japanese from transcript:
汝わが血筋を汝の許にひきて、これに己が肉をさへ顧みざらしめしほどなればこのうえ、何をすべきや！

English from Transcript:
What canst thou more, who has subdued our blood so wholly to thyself, they feel no care of their own flesh?

I think the english translation is not a very direct translation. It helps you get the gist but it doesn't give you the satisfaction to really understand what is said.

Therefore can somebody provide a translation that considers the following points:

- What is the meaning of

  - 許
  - ひきて (Is this a verb?)
  - さへ顧みざらしめしほど

The best that I can come up with is:
You (ひきて = ???) with our lineage (with/in/by?) your (許), if this (さへ顧みざらしめしほど) (with?) my own flesh, (このうえ = Now that things have come to this?) what should I/we do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, his preach does not seem to have been translated very literally (but that does not mean it's a bad translation, of course). To understand this sentence, you need to be familiar with some of the classical Japanese grammar.

Vocab:

- [**許**](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%8B-1): "(someone's) side"
- [**ひきて**](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8F): The ["classical te-form"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17497/5010) of 引く, which means "to draw" or "to inherit" (see the twelfth definition of the link).
- **さへ**: Historical kana version of さえ ("even").
- **顧みざらしめし**: "made (someone/something) not reflect on (it)", "prevented from paying attention to"

  - **顧み**: [顧みる](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%A1%A7%E3%81%BF%E3%82%8B) in irrealis form
  - **ざら**: Negative auxiliary ([ず](https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009020.htm) in irrealis form)
  - **しめ**: Causative auxiliary ([しむ](https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009029.htm) in continuative form). The agent (causee) marked by に is これ, which refers to the 血筋.
  - **し**: Past auxiliary ([き](https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009002.htm) in attributive form)
- **ほど(だ)**:  (∼ くらい(だ)) "to the point where", "it's even that"
- [**この上**](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%8A): "further"

So the literal translation is as follows. I'm not good at "thou art" type English grammar, so allow me to use modern grammar.

> 汝わが血筋を汝の許にひきて、...
> → (現代文) あなたは私の血筋をあなたのもとに引いて、...
>
> You drew/inherited my bloodline to your side, (and) ...

> これに己が肉をさへ顧みざらしめしほどなれば、...
> → それに自分の肉をさえ顧みないようにさせたほどであるから、...
>
> it's even that you made it not reflect even on your own flesh, so ...
> (= Yet you even disallowed my bloodline to worry about your own flesh! Then...)

> このうえ、何をすべきや！
> → このうえ、何をするべきなのか！
>
> What should I/we do further? (= Nothing can be done!)

Comment: To what extent do native Japanese speakers commonly fully understand the meaning of an expression like 顧みざらしめし?

Comment: @jogloran It depends on how much they liked 古文 classes in high school. I would imagine less than 10% of adults can clearly recognize all of ず/ざり, しむ and き the moment they see them, but most can vaguely guess the rough meaning of the text.